# I would like to know the ATMEGA wiring to Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, pins

[image: ATMEGA328 pinout]

I would like to know which pins are connected to the output of the Arduino.

For example:

- PC6 is digital 12
- PB5 is analog 13
- etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Image searching for the term ["arduino uno pinout"](https://www.google.si/search?q=arduino+uno+pinout&tbm=isch) reveals a better pinout diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this image, as it combines the arduino pin numbers and PWM capabilities, with the names and functions from the datasheet.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I usually preferred this image. It very useful for me every time.

[image: Atmega Pin Mapping]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the diagram you are seeking.
[image]

Comment: thanks for your help everyone

just another question
is there another program to implement the code to the arduino
other than the official arduino  program
i need a program where i can debug and put break points like mplab
thanks for your help

Comment: Start a new question...

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply look at the [Arduino Uno schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf), which has everything you should ever need to know.

[image: Uno schematic]

Answer (score -1):

Updated: Pins PB6 & PB7 while available as I/O pins (D6 & D7) are committed to the external crystal on this board and not brought out to the connectors.

Comment: That is not true: you cannot find a connector for XTAL for instance.